# Force.com IDE adds localized fields on sync?

Tags: ide, eclipse, locale

I have a project that I keep in Git and use ant most of the time to deploy it to dev orgs and the production org where we create the package.

When I sync the project with the development environment using the IDE I end up getting a bunch of changes.  Example of such a change is localized fields.

I do have the localization workbench enabled but I have separate objects for various languages.

Is there a way to stop the IDE from adding these fields?

```
.....

    <name>EmailBody__c</name>
</fields>
<fields>
    <label><!-- EmailBody_de --></label>
    <name>EmailBody_de__c</name>
</fields>
<fields>
    <label><!-- EmailBody_es --></label>
    <name>EmailBody_es__c</name>
</fields>
```

.....

Comment: what about excluding the translations from the package? or do you need them?

Comment: The package does support several languages.  I think I do need them.

Answer (score 1):

When the Translation Workbench is enabled to add translations, users work in their language of choice using a language attribute on their user record. Because of that, I'd have to say those are necessary to support your package. If you look at the metadata in your package, I think you'll find they're linked to translation having been enabled.